Фигура-Колонна HTML+CSS
Как сделать фигуру на сайте, а вернее говоря колонну (обвел на фото)
ссылка на шаблон

мой код:


body {
  background-image: url(src/first-screen.png);
  margin: 0;
}

.container {}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #005BC199;
}

.header-line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-logo img {
  max-height: 80px;
}

.header-line img {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 315px;
}

.nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  /*  отступы между элементами навигации */
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300..800;1,300..800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header-line">
        <div class="header-logo">
          <img class="nav-logo" src="src/logo.png">
        </div>
        <nav>
          <a class="nav-item" href="@">О компании</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="@">Портфолио</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="@">Каталог</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="@">Сервис</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="@">Контакты</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




p.s любые ваши советы будут приняты с горячей любовью и должным вниманием

это просто background-image: linear-gradient() для блока container.

@AndreiFedorov можете пожалуйста немного подробнее рассказать

Удивляет, что у вас есть какой-то проект, а вы не знаете элементарных вещей и даже гуглить не умеете.

Ваша колонна - это div - блочный элемент. Просто с определенным уровнем прозрачности и определенным размещением. Для начала создаете header, который будет выполнять роль своеобразного контейнера, в котором будет плавать и Ваше меню, и Ваша колонна и Ваш текстовый контент. Для header задаете position: relative; а для содержимого header (т.е. для колонны, текста и т.д. position: absolute;, чтобы можно было позиционировать элементы на своё усмотрение или в соответствии с макетом. Создаете меню, колонну, текст, раскрашиваете это, как вашей душе угодно, позиционируете на свое усмотрение или в соответствии с макетом, а дальше - по ситуации :-)


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url("https://s3-alpha-sig.figma.com/img/31c0/24d1/19f7ce863b69820d98ffe3b89dc8f2ce?Expires=1719187200&Key-Pair-Id=APKAQ4GOSFWCVNEHN3O4&Signature=kmpOQ8lkcNGXANxMLxE-9VndXyAfhpwp76E8KmVZknXqRhDEq9BXdrdm-8xTg3Awnh9POLdeS8uPfQtJrEDNcqt1MrhlPfGWcqRvGAN-lo4BjVMI~3dPVE7Xpms7qAw-DVhM29eAmNx68cWBt6~KJge89JFTQvFJiAR2vdy70NK6t6aLK3zsuMQ4JF46F10M2jXBzHCCX4tz4neaP4vJ9eRKTwVJho7L0SOgq7FNf6ft4TB3wDTNyJaj9w8fzKgULxYKZG40wDla7ssFhk2AY43HmG43nmcTawYpc3g0sMg4FHbnpPaAUWFnq~ow-TXued0XR5IOlxrJv8tOdCGKbw__");
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.header_menu ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 80px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 91, 193, 0.6);
}

.header_menu li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.header_menu ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.colomn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 444px;
  height: 720px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 91, 193, 0.6);
  top: 80px;
  left: 405px;
}

.text_content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 635px;
  height: 317px;
  top: 282px;
  left: 595px;
}

.text_content h1,
p {
  color: white;
}

button {
  width: 160px;
  height: 51px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
<header>
  <nav class="header_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Портфолио</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Каталог</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Сервис</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="colomn"></div>
  <div class="text_content">
    <h1>Светотехническое оборудование в Петербурге</h1><br>
    <p>Продажа, аренда светотехнического оборудования<br> Оформление официальных мероприятий под ключ</p>
    <button>Перейти</button>
  </div>
</header>



